# How to list all cells selected on a collection view's into another view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm developing an scene using a Split View component. In my master view I have a table view inside a container, and in my detail view I have a collection view inside a container.

[image: Master View Containers]

[image: Detail View containers]

I'm trying get all cells selected on my 'detail view's collection view container' and list on my 'master view table view' but I don't know how to get access from this information. On the detail view I know that I can have the cells selected using "collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()", but how can I access this information outside the view and create a new table cell on the master view table everytime a cell is selected on detail view collection view?

**EDIT:**

I'm reading about delegation and I wrote these code to try to share the data through view but it didn't work:

1) I wrote this delegation protocol:

```
protocol MasterDetailShareDataDelegate: class {
  func reloadMasterViewWithSelectedCells(_ data: Set<String>)
}
```

2) I put the delegate var on the origin view:

```
class ProductsPlatesViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
  var platesSelected: Set<String> = Set()
  var delegate: MasterDetailShareDataDelegate?

  ...

  func passDataBackWards() {
    let data = platesSelected
    delegate?.reloadMasterViewWithSelectedCells(data)
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ProductsPlatesCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    platesSelected = Set()

    for item in collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!  {
      platesSelected.insert(self.plates[item.row])
    }
    passDataBackWards()
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ProductsPlatesCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    platesSelected = Set()

    for item in collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!  {
      platesSelected.insert(self.plates[item.row])
    }
    passDataBackWards()
  }
}
```

3) Wrote this code on the Destiny View:

```
class NewBudgetViewController: UIViewController, MasterDetailShareDataDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let theProductsPlatesViewController = ProductsPlatesViewController()
    theProductsPlatesViewController.delegate = self
    ...
  }


  func reloadMasterViewWithSelectedCells(_ data: Set<String>) {
    print(data)
  }
```

The function reloadMasterViewWithSelectedCells in NewBudgetViewController is not being called. Can someone please tell me why? :(

Comment: Take data of all selected cell to another view and create same cell there.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I wanna do. But how? How can I access the information from another view in real-time (i mean, when the user clicks on the cell from a view, the another views knows it and create the same cell)?

Comment: do you want to for objective C or swift ?

Comment: Swift preferentially.

Comment: How! Just save all selected data in an array and pass that array on next class's array (make it a property). Then use that array as datasource for next class.

Comment: @rptwsthi , could you provide an example of this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case for the delegation design pattern. Design a protocol that will let the collection view controller notify it's delegate about which cells are selected. Make the master view controller the delegate of the collection view controller.

### Edit:

Try a google search on "Swift Delegation pattern" or "Swift delegation tutorial". I found this online that looks to be a decent explanation:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/

### EDIT #2:

Ok, I see that you're using a master/detail design. In that case your master view controller should have a `prepareForSegue` method (`prepare(for:sender:)` in Swift 3). In that method, you should be able to gain access to your destination view controller and set up it's delegate property.

If you don't have a `prepare(for:sender:)` method, add one.

Starting from the code in the master/detail template project from Xcode 8:

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            if let theProductsPlatesViewController = (segue.destination as!
                    UINavigationController).topViewController 
                    as? ProductsPlatesViewController {
                theProductsPlatesViewController.delegate = self
                //Other setup for your detail view controller
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello Duncan. Thanks for your answer. I can understand the concept you described, but I never had to implement my own protocol. Can you provide some code example or some example on the web that is related with this case here? I'm kinda beginning on ios-dev, not sure how to implement this delegation on code :(

Comment: Thanks again. I read the text you posted on your update and i'm trying to make this using delegation, but still dont working. I also edited my posted describing the code I wrote. Please take a look. I'm doing everything in right? :X

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track. Now you need to debug your code. At a glance, I don't see where you set the ProductsPlatesViewController's delegate property. (That could would be in `NewBudgetViewController`, where you create and display the `ProductsPlatesViewController`. It would look something like `theProductsPlatesViewController.delegate = self`.)

Comment: I added these 2 lines on NewBudgetViewContoller viewDidLoad() method: 
`let theProductsPlatesViewController = ProductsPlatesViewController()
theProductsPlatesViewController.delegate = self`

But the method on NewBudgetViewController (that prints the data) is not being called. I'm doing something wrong? I can't see what modify to make this work :(

Comment: Edit your question to show how you're creating the `ProductsPlatesViewController`, configuring it, and displaying it. My guess is that the code you just posted is creating a completely separate instance of `ProductsPlatesViewController` this is never displayed anywhere.

Comment: How do you invoke the detail view controller (class ProductsPlatesViewController?)

Comment: Invoke? What do you mean?

Comment: Your code in `viewDidLoad` is wrong. That code creates a brand-new instance of `ProductsPlatesViewController`, set's it's delegate to self, and then forgets about it. That instance of `ProductsPlatesViewController` has nothing to do with the instance that will display your details. That's like buying a new car, adjusting the mirrors on that new car, throwing away the car, and wondering why the mirrors on your old car haven't been adjusted.

Comment: What code causes your `NewBudgetViewController `to display a detail view controller?

Comment: The NewBudgetViewController is setted as detail controller via StoryBoard, not via code. I understand what you're saying, but I don't know another way to do this. I tried to use     
    `let theProductsPlatesViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "platesVC") as! ProductsPlatesViewController` but I got the same result :(

Comment: "The NewBudgetViewController is setted as detail controller via StoryBoard..." How exactly? (I've never actually used the master/detail project template. I always set up those relationships myself.

Comment: Well. I pressed and hold control + mouse left click into my Split View (on storyboard), and clicked on the New Budget view on StoryBoard and defined Relationship Segue as detail view controller.